# Shutdown_monitor.log > "Security policies don't allow ddt"

Tags: macos, shutdown, console, monterey

Recently, whenever starting my iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015, macOS 12.0.1), I receive a dialog box that says "You shut down your computer because of a problem" on every login.

This has persisted after the following efforts:

- PRAM Reset
- SMC Reset
- OS Reinstall (Monterey, from Recovery Partition)
- Disk Repair First Aid
- Safe Mode boot and shutdown
- New user account boot and shutdown

Puzzled, I scrounged around in logs, and found that `shutdown_monitor.log` has been giving the following message on every shutdown attempt:

```
Sampling completed, generating report...
Security policies don't allow ddt
Security policies don't allow ddt
Security policies don't allow ddt
Security policies don't allow ddt
Security policies don't allow ddt
Security policies don't allow ddt
Saved report to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/shutdown_stall_2021-11-06-001756_my_mac_name.shutdownStall
```

Searching for `Security policies don't allow ddt` has amazingly produced no hits on Google at all! Does anybody know what the above message means, or how I can dig deeper to determine what is causing the failed shutdowns?

Potentially related factors:

- The Fusion Drive that came with my Mac gave up the ghost so I am using a 3rd party SSD
- I recently had a power outage, after which I noticed this issue (but I hadn't shut down my mac for weeks before that, so it may not have been related)

Answer (score 1):

It is basically taking a sample of a process which is misbehaving using a tool called `spindump`

These dumps are stored in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` you can see the  `shutdownStall` files and where and when they were created in the `shutdown_monitor.log`

These `shutdownStall` files are in a `Spindump binary format` so you cannot see what is happing, however, you can convert them into plain text.

Go to terminal

```
sudo spindump -i  /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/shutdown_stall < file name here> .shutdownStall
```

it should return the location of the generated text file e.g

```
Spindump analysis written to file /tmp/spindump.txt
```

you can then view the text file with your tool of choice e.g

```
 less /tmp/spindump.txt
```

In this file you can see what was happening in the system

with Monterey I am having a few issues with

```
Process:          BTLEServerAgent [990]
```

This is to do with Bluetooth LE which seems to be right because I am having issues with my Mac randomly forgetting my BOSE headphones pairing. Others seem to be having other Bluetooth issues some of them being around waking from sleep.

I am waiting for a fix, however, it doesn’t effect me much.